# How to force UISearchBar text into uppercase in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am trying to force `UISearchBar` textfield to uppercase when the user is typing.

This is what I have tried, however it's not working.

```
  UISearchBar *filterSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 170.0, 280.0, 40.0)];
  filterSearchBar.delegate = self;
  filterSearchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters; 
  [allBackGroundView addSubview:filterSearchBar];
```

Comment: That's the right code. What happens when you type in the search field? Are you sure that is the search bar being used?

Comment: when I type it shows in lower case and will only go upper case if I use the shift key on the keyboard. 100% positive this is the correct UISearchBar.

Comment: Are you doing this in the Simulator while typing on your computer's keyboard? That isn't a valid test. Test by tapping on the actual keyboard in the app or test on a real device. Using the computer's keyboard in the simulator doesn't honor text field/view capitalization properly.

Comment: I am testing on actual device. going to try the answer below

Comment: Turns out bluetooth keyboard was preveting this from working correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Use below SearchBar delegate method for the force uppercase letters

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
        searchBar.text = searchText.uppercaseString;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.text = searchText.uppercaseString
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the search bar delegate methods to do this. I don't have Xcode open to test this, but this should work...

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
     searchText = [searchText uppercaseString];
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this and its not working.. I will look into a similar solution unless you have any more ideas. I think its not woking cause searchText is never returned from this method **(void)** so will look into other searchBar delegate methods